# Turn Image border On and Off With A click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have three images on a page. So far I can set the JavaScript so that when a user clicks an image the border show's up on it. I would also like it so that when a user clicks the same image again the border disappears. Basically anytime a user clicks a picture the border on that image will go on and off with every click. Can someone please help me out? I am also NOT ALLOWED TO USE JQUERY

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use document.getElementById(id).style.border to get the current border of the image, and then use document.getElementById(id).style.border = 'none'; to turn it off. If it were me I'd make a toggle function that takes the image id and does all the work.

Comment: is there an example you could show me? I am not familiar with the toggle function?

Answer (score 0):

This accomplishes your goal. You can always compartmentalize it by moving the `onclick` contents to a separate function that is called.

http://jsfiddle.net/7kR6e/1/